# Драйтулинг

Tags: словообразование

Есть такой вид спорта "драйтулинг". Как будет называться женщина, занимающаяся этим видом спорта.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Драйтулинг+ист+к+а =

*Драйтулингистка*

Answer (score 0):

драй-ту-лú-ха
Драуйтулúха

Answer (score 0):

Грамматика названа верная: драйтулинг-ист-к-а, по аналогии с "альпинистка", других вариантов для нейтрального стиля нет. Произнести тоже можно, фонетика не очень трудная. НО сложно  сказать, будет ли оно использоваться.

О НАЗВАНИЯХ http://burevestnik.uz/forum/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=460

"Рассмотрим спортсмена с ледовыми инструментами в руках, на ногах у него ботинки с кошками, на голове - каска. Возможные варианты: Если он лезет по льду, то вопросов не возникает. Это ледолаз и он лезет ледовый маршрут. Если лед перемежается участками скал, то говорят, что спортсмен (тоже ледолаз) лезет микстовый маршрут. А вот во всех остальных случаях как раз и будет Dry-Tooling. А спортсмен, несмотря ни на что, по прежнему называется ледолазом.

Comment: А  почему  лезет,  а  не  проходит ?  Сленг ?

Comment: Наверное, сленг, то есть лексика, характерная для  определенных групп лиц, связанных общими интересами, занятиями. Лезет маршрут - так могут сказать только профессионалы.